# React Native modal - fire function when dismissing through swipe

Tags: react-native

I am using `Modal` from `react-native`, `presentational-style="pageSheet"` which means I can slide to dismiss. However when I do that, no function is fired. onDismiss only fires when I close it from a button. Any idea of what I am missing here? The modal won't open again if I do like this because it doesn't change it's state.

Comment: Can you share your code? Can you create an example in https://snack.expo.io?

Comment: Sure! https://snack.expo.io/@yarism/arrogant-tortilla - it's no problem if you follow the buttons but as soon as you swipe down the modal then it won't be possible to open again.

Comment: i've got the same problem. did you find a solution? i have it so when i swipe it away, there's a blank screen below and therefore I can't navigate anywhere

Comment: @LiamChapman no I haven't, I changed from pageSheet due to this issue but I can't find a way to report this to the react team.